# How would you sketch this subset of $\mathbb{C}$ without a calculator?

Tags: complex-numbers

My question is how would you sketch a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ where $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\arg(z^{3})\in(0,\pi)\}$?

I tried without a calculator and couldn't seem to find the answer or a method via google or textbooks.

Comment: Using the polar form of complex numbers can you figure out $\arg (z^3)$ in terms of $\arg (z)$?

Comment: Could you expand? I don't understand exactly

Comment: Are you familiar with the polar form of complex numbers? Put a number in that form then cube it. See what happens to the argument.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $z = r e^{i\theta}$, you have that $arg (z^3) = arg(r^3 e^{3i \theta})= 3 \theta$. So, the complex numbers in that set will have arguments that satisfy $0 < 3 \theta < \pi$. I believe you can now conclude.

Comment: Shouldn't that also include $2\pi<3\theta<3\pi$ and $4\pi<3\theta<5\pi$?

Comment: @Sandejo That just depends on what you are assuming on $\theta$, for instance if it is the principal argument or not.